# Mongodb TypeError: vehicle.save is not a function

Tags: mongodb, api, mongoose-schema

When I perform a delete request, it returns an error stating that `save` is not a function

```
const Vehicle = require('../models/vehicle');
router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('id: ', req.params.id);
    
    const vehicle = await Vehicle.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id});
    
    try {
        vehicle.save();
        res.send('ok');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('err: ', error);
        res.send(error);
    }
});
```

vehicle's schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const vehicle = new mongoose.Schema({
    AID: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    OwnerName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    OwnerNIC: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    PhoneNo: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    VehicleName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    EngineNo: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ChasisNo: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    NoPlate: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    RegFees: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Vehicle', vehicle);
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see some mistakes in your code.

1. Incorrectly wrapping the `await` with the `try-catch` block.
2. Irrelevant use of the mongoose `save()`. You don't need to use the `save()` method when performing a `delete` request.

Your code should be changed like this:

```
const Vehicle = require('../models/vehicle');
router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('id: ', req.params.id);
    try {
        await Vehicle.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id});
        res.send('Vehicle deleted.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('err: ', error);
        res.send(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const Vehicle = require('../models/vehicle');

router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('id: ', req.params.id);
   
     await Vehicle.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id}).then((result) => {
      console.log('Result: ', result);
      if (result.n > 0) {
        res.status(200).json({ message: "Vehicle Deleted" });
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({ message: "Error to delete " });
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Not Delete" });
    });
});
```